# VAR-model include constant or not?

Tags: regression, vector-autoregression, intercept

I am estimating a var model with four variables: GDP, investemnt, inflation and unemployment. (all in growth rates). Now I estimated it once with a constant and one without. The model is not changing much but when I calculate the irf functions of the gdp after a shock in investment it is only significant when I dont add a constant to the model. Now my question is if I should include a constant in the model and live with the insignificant results or if I should continue with the model without constant.

Can someone help me ? :)

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have growth rates or first differences here. Accordingly, adding a constant may imply a linear trend in logarithms or levels. You may want to think whether that is reasonable.

Comment: Yes sorry I didnt specify enough. I have all variables in growth rates and yes in levels I have in nearly all variables a linear trend